# OSSEC integrity checksum alert - what caused the change?

Tags: linux, ossec

Recently installed OSSEC on Linux machine to test.

Most results are expected, however yesterday I received emails with a number of notifications about Integrity checksum changing on files such as
  /usr/bin/whoami
  /usr/bin/md5sum
  /usr/bin/ls
    and about another 50 similar files

Since I didn't install any new versions of these files, how do I find out what caused the integrity checksum to change 2 days after I installed the OSSEC program?

Eureka

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons are:

- You've actually been hacked
- [Prelinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelinking) is enabled

You can disable prelinking by editing /etc/sysconfig/prelink from:

```
PRELINKING=yes
```

to:

```
PRELINKING=no
```

And running:

```
prelink -ua
```

Source: http://www.ossec.net/wiki/Know_How:Check_Sums

Comment: Thank you very much. That has explained the constant changes I saw. I then did some further searching and also found information on another option as well Source: http://www.mail-archive.com/ossec-list@googlegroups.com/msg04568.html